# I want to get only selected children array objected from jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

Am using http://www.jstree.com

i used `var nodes=$('#jstree').jstree("get_json");` this code and i got follow object as result
[image]

. I just want only get children as like this.
how to get that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_json` function, just pass in the optional ID (the node from which to begin):
`var nodes=$('#jstree').jstree("get_json","NODE-ID-HERE").children;`

Keep in mind this approach will give you the children of the children too, but you can simply ignore those. If that does now work for you - loop through the result and remove the children property.

```
var instance = $('#jstree').jstree(true),
    children = instance.get_json("NODE-ID-HERE").children,
    i, j;
for(i = 0, j = children.length; i < j; i++) {
    delete children[i].children;
    delete children[i].children_d;
}
// children is now an array of all the node's children, but without their children
```